# Why isn't AutoDetectChangesEnabled set to false by default?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I was wondering why the `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` property on the DbContext is set to false by default.

I want to bulk insert into my context and as you might know turning the auto-detection to false brings way better performances.

I mean, if i know when to detect the changes to my context, is there any reason why i shouldn't set `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false`?

Comment: My guess is that the EF team thought that bulk uploading was an edge case compared to regular CRUD style operations... and thus defaulted to the common requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is likely they wanted the more common and very useful behavior to  work out of the box.

```
var mycontext = new DemoContext();
var myEntity = myContent.Thinhymybobs.find(akey);
myEntity.PropX = newvalue;
mycontext.saveChnages();
```

The update sent to the the DB is delta aware and the update set statement is used accordingly.
So this is friendly on the DB.

When doing "bulk" operations on a DB, performance questions are normally a natural thought. So wondering about turning change off or indeed EVEN using tracking is a likely question i feel.

This article may interest you.  State of an entry.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I also thought this was the reason why but I wanted someone else's opinion